# How to concatenate varchar into a string in Redshift table

Tags: amazon-redshift, string-aggregation

I have a table as follows:

```
create table #t1(a1 varchar(2))

insert into #t1 select 'AA'
insert into #t1 select 'BB'
```

I want final result as follows: Which aggregation function should I use.

```
'AA,BB'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [LISTAGG Function - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_LISTAGG.html):

```
select listagg(sellerid, ', ') within group (order by sellerid) from sales
where eventid = 4337;

listagg                                                                                                                                 
----------------------------------------------------
380, 380, 1178, 1178, 1178, 2731, 8117, 12905, 32043
```